# Несколько экземпляров одного компонента на странице React + Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

подскажите пожалуйста, использую react + redux. Создал на странице несколько экземпляров одного компонента . 
В компоненте есть кнопка, при нажатии меняется состояние не только того экземпляра на котором нажимаю, 
а сразу всех экземпляров этого компонента, которые есть на странице.

(В конечном итоге, компонент выводится вот в таком виде .....(NavbarToggler))

файл NavbarToggler.tsx : https://pastebin.com/Bim0MC2Z

файл NavbarToggler.ts : https://pastebin.com/ewVbUQ07

файл компонента, из которого вызывается компонент NavbarToggler: https://pastebin.com/cbEePszq

На странице, компонент отображается как:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в чём, собственно, вопрос? :)

Comment: скорее всего ваши компоненты зависят от 1-й переменной в Store, она меняется и все ваши компоненты следом за ней)